# Convert 16-bit signed PCM to usigned 16-bit

Tags: unsigned, signed, pcm

I have a audio wave file (*.wav) and I have the audio data formatted in signed 16-bit (from -32767 to +32768).
I want to convert them in unsigned 16-bit (from 0 to +65535).
Is there some idea how to do that using audacity, sox ot any other otol?
Even a c programm is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Would you please react on comments and answers of your previous question? Read the FAQ about using this site.

Comment: Sorry owlstead, I diddn't find where I can vote your answer. I am so sorry !!!

Comment: That's OK, just try and not abandon questions in the future, welcome back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add 32768 to each sample.  Note that this is equivalent to inverting the MSB (most-significant bit) of each sample.

Comment: Are you sure "Note that this is equivalent to inverting the MSB of each sample."

Comment: @user1907957: Assuming a 2's-complement representation (which is almost certainly the case), then yes.

Comment: Thnak you Oli for the useful answer

Answer (score 0):

In Audacity trying using the export command. (FILE - Export )